# Is there a way to run something after a WebAPI call using an Attribute or something alternative in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, aop

I would like to be running specific code after a Web API call happens. I would also like to know its inputs and output so I can figure out what I would like to do in the process

e.g

```
public TestController : ApiController {

  [Route("test/{testId}")]
  [RunAfter(testId, test)]
  public void updateTest(int testId, [FromBody] Test test){

  }
}
```

If Attributes cannot be used after a web api call. What is the proper way of doing it while still using WebAPI? I would like to avoid calling those process functions in the controller methods if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own `ActionFilterAttribute` just by deriving from that class.

Then, you can `override` the `OnActionExecuted` method and you should be all set.

See [here for documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx). Be aware, there are two `ActionFilterAttributes` with different namespaces, one for MVC, one for WebAPI.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to know what exactly happened during execution? Like what inputs were given and what was returned for example?

Comment: a few things, yes. You will be passed an HttpActionContext with a few properties, such as ActionArguments , Response, ModelState and so on. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.httpactioncontext(v=vs.118).aspx)